# In Apex 5, is it possible to execute multiple Automatic Row Processing, on the same form, inserting/updating on different tables?

Tags: oracle-apex-5

In Apex 5, i'm trying to execute multiple Automatic Row Processing(ARP), on the same form, inserting/updating on different tables. But after the first ARP, that performs a insert on the first table, the subsequent ARPs tries to use the fields of the first table for the insert of the subsequent ARPs.

Can i separate the fields that participate in each ARP, or is it a limitation of Apex 5, that i must use only 1 ARP on 1 form page, inserting/updating on 1 table?

Comment: in my 2 years of using apex 5, i have never found a way to specify what table the items(fields) you labeled(source) as database columns belonged to.I always have to make a process that manually inserts/updates the other table.

Comment: That is what it seems, a limitation of Apex 5. And so far, thats what the evidences point to.